# spree link_to static page

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, spree

Добрый день. Не могу понять, почему не работает link_to... Объясните пожалуйста.

```
# routes.rb
get '/about' => 'spree/home#about', :as => :about
```

Путь до вьюхи: `app/views/spree/home/about.html.erb`

В другой вьюхе такой линк:

```
<li><%= link_to "about", about_path %> </li>
```

В `rake routes`:

```
about_path      GET     /about(.:format)         spree/home#about
```

Что я делаю не так?

Ошибка:

```
NameError in Spree::Home#index

undefined local variable or method `about_path' for #<#<Class:0x00000005230f28>:0x007fdff9daa1c0>

Did you mean?  account_path
               logout_path
```

Comment: А что у вас, собственно, не так? Ошибка? Если да - то какая? (можно дополнить вопрос)

Comment: обновил вопрос.

Comment: А роут до монтирования спрее или после?